# Interjecting into the nib loading process

Tags: ios, loading, nib

My iOS app can be rebranded by downloading a zip file with new images and strings. This can happen at any time. Since I can't replace the files inside the app bundle, I have to check to see if there's a new image / string every time I load a nib, then replace what was setup in IB. I'd much rather have this automated. Any thoughts on how to interject myself into the nib loading process to do this? Most of my nibs are loaded by UIViewController subclasses.

I'm already doing the check in viewDidLoad:. But that means I have to remember to do it in each UIViewController subclass, and I have to know which outlets in the nib need twiddling. What I'd like is to be able to interject in the actual nib loading process so that when the system goes to get the "flower.png" image that was specified in the nib, I get a chance to return something other than the "flower.png" in the app bundle.

Strings may be harder to handle in this manner, but ideally I could hack in there as well.

Comment: couldn't you create a patient class and just call the method in all the viewDidLoads?

Comment: I assume you mean "parent" class. As in, a subclass of UIViewController that is the parent of all my "real" view controllers? And which has outlets for all the bits that I want to tweak and does the tweaking in its -viewDidLoad method. Yeah, that's the easiest way to do it. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Ye sorry parent class. Been working at a hospital all day :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

geminiCoder pointed me in the right direction - a subclass of UIViewController that is the parent of all my "real" view controllers. And which has outlets for all the bits that I want to tweak and does the tweaking in its -viewDidLoad method. That way, all the "real" view controllers inherit the outlets and just hook them up to the right UI elements and they automatically get updated.